# How to check if an element from an array is being repeated in another array. All these arrays are inside of a Multidimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

basically I'm looping through each element from each array trying to find an element that is also an element from another array, and if there's an element that is being repeated in another array I want to print out that element as well as **STOPING the loop**.
In simply words this is what I have:

```
def list = [[2,3,5,10,13], [12,23,9,8], [34,11,14,15,67,28,5], [7,23,67,27,30,33]]
```

**IMPORTANT**: An element will never show up two times in the same array

I need to loop through the elements of each array and compare it to the other elements from other arrays, and if there's an element that is being repeated **(Example: 5 - this number is being repeated in array1 and array3)** then my loop should STOP. I've being stuck on this for a while. Does anyone know how to solve this in Groovy please? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Is it Java at all?

Comment: @Vadim Its Groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[][] list = {{2,3,5,10,13}, {12,23,9,8}, {34,11,14,15,67,28,5}, {7,23,67,27,30,33}};
HashSet<Integer> seenItems = new HashSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    int[] l = list[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < l.length; j++) {
        int itemToCheck = l[j];
        if (seenItems.contains(itemToCheck)) {
            System.out.println("We've already seen " + itemToCheck);
            return;
        } else {
            seenItems.add(itemToCheck);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of values of the lists please?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mate!

Comment: @AlejandroC. what happens if an element appears two times in the same array?

Comment: @HenryDev if an element appears two times in the same array method will stop returning that number.. is it ok for you?

Comment: @user6904265 an element will never show up two times in the same array

Answer (score 2):

```
def list = [
    [2,3,5,10,13], 
    [12,23,9,8], 
    [34,11,14,15,67,28,5], 
    [7,23,67,27,30,33]
]

list.flatten().countBy { it }.findResult { k, v -> v > 1 ? k : null }
```

Comment: voting it up. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

**Declare Bidimensional-Array**

```
 Integer [][]a = {{2,3,5,10,13}, {12,23,9,8}, {34,5,11,14,15}, {7,23,67,27,30,33}};
```

**Looking for the number with intersection between Sets**

```
boolean numberFound = false;
int number=0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length && !numberFound; i++){
    for (int j = i+1; j < a.length && !numberFound; j++) {
        HashSet<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a[i]));
        intersection.retainAll(Arrays.asList(a[j]));
        if(intersection.size()>0){
            numberFound = true;
            number = intersection.iterator().next().intValue();
        }
    }
}
```

**Printing**

```
if(numberFound){
    System.out.println("Number found is: " +number);
} else{
    System.out.println("Number not found");
}
```

**UPDATE**

If we are sure that an element will never show up two times in the same array we can use this code:

```
Entry<Integer, Long> entry = Arrays.stream(a)
 .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
   .boxed()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
       .entrySet()
        .stream()
         .filter(s -> s.getValue() > 1)
          .findAny()
           .orElse(null);

if(entry == null){
 System.out.println("Number not found");
}else {
 System.out.println("Number found: " + orElse.getKey());
}
```

Comment: You have to write a Groovy implementation of Streams. Above usage of Lambdas will not be acceptable in current Groovy code (if OP is using a Groovy source). You can replace Predicates with Groovy Closures and Java 8 method references with method pointers in Groovy.

Comment: @dmahapatro I agree with you, I did it in java because I'm more familiar with the language (and I saw also the java tag in this question). Anyway the logic behind the algorithm is very similar to that of groovy. Finally, I voted up your answer, I think the OP should accept it because it is what he was looking for.

Comment: I can bet you will enjoy Groovy. Java 8 has great features but all of them has been available in Groovy a long time ago. Just take a look at http://groovy-lang.org/ and also play around it using the web console https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ . It is as simple as `println 'Hello World'` ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your hints, I'll try it! ;-)